# In jetty websocket framework, what is the difference between WebSocketConnectionListener and WebSocketSessionListener?

Tags: websocket, jetty, java-websocket

I am new to using jetty websockets. I came across two implementations of the above two listeners -

1. WebSocketConnectionListener (provided in package org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api)
2. WebSocketSessionListener (provided in package org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common)

I do not understand the difference between these two websocket libraries. Are they intended for different purposes or can we just choose any one and work? (Personally, I have used the WebsocketPartialListener child interface (which extends WebSocketConnectionListener) to deal with partial binary messages)

I went through the documentation but wasn't clear on the differences between these two. I have prior idea about using jakarta websockets where we have Partial and Whole message handlers and tried relating the above two interfaces with that. I have a hunch that WebsocketSessionListener might be used for whole messages (and not partial chunks with isFinal parameter in argument of onMessage method). But I am not sure of this. Can someone guide here please?